# horizontal bar chart with time: tooltip only works with last item

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs

I'm currently trying to recreate a machine timeline using chart-js and momentum.
The current state already looks like the original, but there are some points that are not working as expected.

- the tooltip is only shown for the last bar (on the right)
- the legend shows the 3 states a lot, but each should only be shown once

working example
https://codepen.io/tulipuser/pen/PoXmRQR

Expected result:
[image]

As shown in the image, each state should be visible once.
And every tooltip should work, not only the last one.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart =   new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
              labels: ['Status'],
              datasets: [{label:'RUNNING',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(101,172,91,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T08:56:26.000Z',y:0}]},
              {label:'IDLE',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(233,157,82,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T09:39:12.000Z',y:1}]},
              {label:'RUNNING',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(101,172,91,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T09:42:44.000Z',y:2}]},
              {label:'STOPPED',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(212,29,29,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T10:00:11.000Z',y:3}]},
              {label:'RUNNING',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(101,172,91,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T12:30:00.000Z',y:4}]},
              {label:'IDLE',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(233,157,82,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T12:55:23.000Z',y:5}]},
              {label:'RUNNING',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(101,172,91,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T19:00:12.000Z',y:6}]},
              {label:'IDLE',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(233,157,82,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-01T21:12:45.000Z',y:7}]},
              {label:'RUNNING',borderWidth:1,backgroundColor:'rgba(101,172,91,1)',data:[{x:'2023-09-02T02:12:12.000Z',y:8}]}],
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                  x: {
                    stacked: false,
                    min: '2023-09-01T08:56:26.000Z',
                    //OP "min: moment().startOf('day').subtract(11, 'day')" worked only on the first day
                    type: 'time',
                        time: {
                            unit: 'minute',
                             displayFormats: {
                                hour: 'H:mm'
                              },
                        }
                  },
                  y: {
                    stacked: true
                  }
                },
            indexAxis: 'y',
            }
        });
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/chart.js@latest/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/4.4.0/chart.min.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-adapter-moment/1.0.1/chartjs-adapter-moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="myChartDiv">
  <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `interaction.mode: 'dataset'` to `options` as follows and it will work.

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  interaction: {
    mode: 'dataset'
  },
  ...
```

For further details, consult chapter [Interactions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#modes) from `Chart.js` documentation.

The same result can be obtained by defining `options.plugins.tooltip.mode: 'dataset'` as shown below (see [Tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html)).

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      mode: 'dataset'
    }
  },
  ...
```